# How to reference a java project in my android project?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am making an android app. I have created a java project also that uses BufferedImage to manipulate images. I want to use this project in my android project. How can I do that?

I'm using eclipse. When I right click my android project > properties > android > [add]
my java project isn't in the available options. I think I need to somehow mark it as library.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of creating it as java project, create it as Library project. I am not sure whether you can make existing java project as library project or not.

Comment: I don't see any "Library" type project when I create a new project.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your Java project to your build path:

Right click on your Android project, click on Properties. In the dialog, select Java Build Path, and then click on the Projects tab. There, add your Java project to the build path.

Comment: The java project has a `public static void main(String args[])`. Will it get run automatically this way?

Comment: No, because you are not actually executing the project. You are just adding the project as library, so you can access its classes and methods from your Android project.

Answer (score 1):

make JAR of your BufferedImage project and then copy it inside your new project, then right click on the JAR in Eclipse and Choose Build Path -> Add to classpath or something like that